# HTTP proxy server python [client side help]

Tags: python, sockets, http, proxy, client

I thought it would be cool to implement this proxy server. Currently very new to socket programming but how would you go about making a client side program which will interact with the proxy and will send HTTP GET requests to multiple web servers through the proxy (ex: reddit.com, google.com, yahoo.com)? Also how would i run the proxy to test that it is working?

Code for the proxy:

```
from socket import *
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print 'Usage : Python ProxyServer.py server_ip"\n[server_ip : It is the IP address of Proxy Server'
sys.exit(2)
#create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening
tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerPort = 8888
tcpSerSock.bind(("", tcpSerPort))
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while 1:
#start recieving data from the client
    print 'Ready to serve...'
tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
print 'Recieved a connection from:', addr
message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024)
print message

#extract the filename from a given message
print message.split()[1]
filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2]
print filename
fileExist = "false"
filetouse = "/" + filename
print filetouse

try:
#check wether the file exists in the cache
    f = open(filetouse[1:], "r")
    outputdata = f.readlines()
    fileExist = "true"
    tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
    tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n")
    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
        tcpCliSock.send(outputdata[i])
    print 'Read from cache'

#Error handeling for file not in cache

except IOError:
    if fileExist == "false":
#creates a socket on the proxyserver
        c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
hostn = filename.replace("www.","",1)
print hostn
try:
#connect to the socket to port 80 
    c.connect(hostn,80)
#creates a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80 for the file requested by the client
    fileobj = c.makefile('r', 0)
    fileobj.write("GET "+"http://" + filename + "HTTP/1.0\n\n") 

    #read the response into buffer
    #create a new file in the cache for the requested file
    #also, send the response in the buffer to client socket and the corresponding file in the cache
    tmpFile = open("./" + filename,"wb")
    for i in range(0, len(buff)):
        tmpFile.write(buff[i])
    tcpCliSock.send(buff[i])
except:
    print "Illegal Request"
else:
#HTTP response message for file not found
    print "404 Error file not found"
#close the client and the server sockets
tcpCliSock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using OS X 10.10.3 and Python 3.4

Links to screenshots of the code as well:
https://smartedblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/pr4-1.png (part 1)
https://smartedblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/pr4-2.png (part 2)

Comment: Is this supposed to be an HTTP proxy? If so the protocol is documented, why would you need a special client. Try e.g. `curl` with the `--proxy` option to test.

Comment: So should i open up 2 terminals one with running the proxy(file name Proxyserver.py) : python Proxyserver.py and how should i format the second command to call and test the proxy?

Comment: `curl --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8888" "http://your.url.here/"`

Comment: i ran the proxy and typed in: `curl --proxy curl --proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8888" "http//:www.google.com/"` and received: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused`

Comment: Did you specify `curl --proxy` twice? If `127.0.0.1` does not work try `localhost`. If that still does not work, time to improve your socket knowledge and check where your proxy is actually listening :).

Answer (score 0):

You have a while loop that never breaks.

```
while 1:
    print 'Ready to serve...'
```

What is your proxy output? It looks like it should just print that line ad-infinitum. Your proxy never gets to this line `tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()` to accept a connection.

Comment: The proxy should output a webpage once a client sends an HTTP GET request. Im having a little trouble getting to that point by not being able to connect some client program to it

Comment: @MattMontalbano I understand, but the way you have it written, the proxy will not accept a connection because it never hits the line `tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()`. Can you verify what the proxy outputs when you start it?